# Added control to form has no name

Tags: c#, wpf

I am completely noob in WPF. I have just opened MS Visual Studio Express 2013 Preview and I am trying to do some "Hello World!" app. I have noticed when I am adding a control to form, for example a TextBox, that control has no name assign.

Is this normal? And how can I change its properties from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF, a control needs a name to be provided almost exclusively for the following reasons only:

- The developer wants to reference the control in code-behind (frowned upon when using MVVM but sometimes necessary)
- When the developer will be passing the XAML to a testing team that is using an automated UI testing tool
- When a Binding on another control is using ElementName to reference a property on that control.

If it's not one of those, there's really no need to name your controls. You'll find, once you start using MVVM as your principal design pattern, that you rarely need to know the names of your controls in code. Start getting used to changing properties in XAML, not code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Name` attribute and provide a unique identifier:

```
<TextBox Name="UniqueName">
  Value
</TextBox>
```

Assigning the `Name` value in code could only be achieved if you found a way to actually locate the control *without* a name in the first place - a little long-winded rather than using the markup, unless, that is, you're adding the controls to the window dynamically anyway, and so already have a direct reference to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Add "Name" attribute

Msdn doc :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> that control has no name assign. Is it normal? How can I change its properties from code

after creating the control, you can access all it's properties like

```
Textbox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Name = "textBox1";
tb.Text = "Hello world";
someStackPanel.Children.Add(tb);
```